# EC2 Instance profiles using expired credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

This is the setup:

There is a Master-Worker architecture which is being orchestrated via Ansible from inside of Master. The code for creating the Workers is as follows:

```
- name: Provisioning Spot instaces
  ec2:
    assign_public_ip: no
    spot_price: "{{ ondemand4_price }}"
    spot_wait_timeout: 300
    assign_public_ip: no
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    image: "{{ image_instance }}"
    instance_type: "{{ large_instance }}"
    key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
    count: "{{ ninstances }}"
    state: present
    group_id: "{{ priv_sg }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet_id }}"
    instance_profile_name: 'ML-Ansible'
    wait: true
    instance_tags:
      Name: Worker
    #delete_on_termination: yes
  register: ec2
  ignore_errors: True
```

So, the Worker instances are created with a profile name (/role) 'ML-Ansible' which contains all the necessary permissions.

However, when trying to execute an AWS shell command (`aws cloudwatch put-metric-data ...`), but it returns the following error:

```
"stderr": "\nAn error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the PutMetricData operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.",
```

We have recently rotated all our credentials. So, we have a fresh set of `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`

So, when I looked at my `~/.aws/credentials` file, it contains the previous set of credentials even when the Ansible file was run today.

**Why is it happening?** Any change needed to be done in the corresponding IAM profile too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`, then most likely they were put there before the AMI was created and now are baked into the AMI used to launch your workers.

If you are using your own AMI (and not an AWS-provided one), try re-creating it after removing the credentials.